# Launch sublime text 3 in git bash from windows path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Sublime Text 3

Tags: windows, git, bash, sublimetext3

I need to run sublime 3 on windows 10. Sublime installation directory is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Sublime Text 3.

I tried these;

```
$ c:/Program\ Files\(\x86\)/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe

$ c:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe

$ c:/Program\ Files(x86)/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe;
```

I get syntax error, and `No such file or directory` on several attempts.

Comment: I think the first of these was very close to correct, you just didn't need to escape the 'x'.

`C:/Program\ Files\(x86\)/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe`

Did you ever try that version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Double-Quote` the `path` and **remove** all  back-slashes (`\`) , i.e.:

```
$ "D:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe"
```

Comment: I had my path like this: $ "c:\Program Files (x86)\Sublime Text 3\Sublime_text.exe"
I worked just fine and launched sublime text from my x86 folder. Thanks.

Comment: To add alias to .bash_profile while using git bash: 
alias subl="'c:\Program Files (x86)\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe'"
The path should be in both double and single quotes

Answer (score 5):

This is what i did.

Create a file .bash_profile under C:\Users\UserName

In .bash_profile file i typed it as

> alias 'subl= "/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe"'